# Spring Boot & Redis - How can I use the Lettuce client

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce

I'm trying to uses a Redis client in my Spring Boot application.
As I understand the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

includes both Jedis and Lettuce clients. I made the choice of Lettuce.

In my SpringBoot application I have :

```
@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
}
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

In my controller I'm trying something very simple :

```
private final RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
public MyApplicationController(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
}

@GetMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    System.out.println(redisTemplate.opsForValue().increment("count"));
}
```

In my Redis command line I tried

```
$ INCR count
$ 1
$ INCR count
$ 2
$ KEYS *
$ 1) "count"
$ get count
$ "2"
```

For the incr command in my redis-cli monitor I see

```
1605772858.314326 [0 172.18.0.6:49646] "incr" "count"
```

So it's working fine.

Now I'm using my Spring Boot application.

After calling the /test endpoint I see

```
1605773023.329581 [0 172.18.0.1:57032] "INCR" "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x05count"
```

And

```
keys *
1) "��\u0000\u0005t\u0000\u0005count"
2) "count"
```

In the Spring Boot console I see 1.  A second call to the /test gives me 2.  So it seems it is incrementing but ... why does the key have that strange name ?
What's the problem in my code ?

**Solution 1**

In my SpringBoot application I now have :

```
@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
}
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

The `System.out.println(redisTemplate.opsForValue().increment("count"));` give me

```
1605778686.384734 [0 172.18.0.1:60768] "INCR" "count"
```

`System.out.println(redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("count"));` :

```
1605778707.217075 [0 172.18.0.1:60788] "GET" "count"
```

It seems ok but

```
2020-11-19 10:38:28.253 ERROR 13512 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.EOFException] with root cause
```

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` only provides the Lettuce client, not the Jedis client. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jedis-instead-of-lettuce.

Comment: How do I get the Jedis client then?